# char 2D array compression

Tags: c#

There is a .txt file what I have to **read**, **compress** and make an output txt for the **compressed** txt. Could anyone tell me what should I fix in my code?

***My code:***

```
namespace Tomorites
{
    class Compression
    {
        public void Compress(char[,] source)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < source.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                int white = 0;                           
                int red = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < source.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if (source[i, j] == 'P')
                    { 
                        if (source[i, j] > 0)
                        {
                            red++;
                            Console.Write(red + " P ");
                        }                                              
                    }                    
                    else if(source[i,j]=='F')
                    {
                        if (source[i, j] > 0)
                        {
                            white++;
                            Console.Write(white + " F ");
                        }                                            
                    }                                       
                }               
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[My console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsWbL.png)

[Source txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flaCJ.png)

[The compressed txt file which has to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgsKZ.png)

Comment: Please review [posting homework question guidelines](ttps://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [MRE], than [edit] question to include necessary details as *text* in the question. Also clarify what debugging you already done.

Comment: It looks to me like you are printing on every character, and you'd like to only print to the screen when the current character changes. In addition to printing the character, you'd like to reset the counter to zero.

Comment: Yeah,I'd like to count and reset when the next character is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was pretty close, but messed one important thing: **reset** first char counter when second char appear or second char counter when first char appear.

Also `source[i, j] > 0` condition do **nothing** for you.

So at result we may have:

**Fill** source array:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Declare array
    char[,] source = new char[7, 10];

    // Fill array as at example
    for (int i = 0; i < source.GetLength(0); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < source.GetLength(1); j++)
            source[i, j] = i == 3 || j == 3 ? 'F' : 'P';

    // Print filled array to Console
    Console.WriteLine("Source:\n" + new string('-', 10));
    for (int i = 0; i < source.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < source.GetLength(1); j++)
            Console.Write(source[i, j] + " ");

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    // Just new line
    Console.WriteLine();

    // Now "compress"
    Console.WriteLine("Compressed:\n" + new string('-', 10));
    Compress(source);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Source output:

[image]

**Compress** source array:

```
static void Compress(char[,] source)
{
    // Declare counters for P and F chars
    int PCount = 0, FCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < source.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < source.GetLength(1); j++)
        {    
            if (source[i, j] == 'P')
            {
                // If char is P - then count P's up
                PCount++;
                // If there was F char counted before (> 0) - print it and reset counter
                if (FCount > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(FCount + " F ");
                    FCount = 0;
                }
            }
            else if (source[i, j] == 'F')
            {
                // If char is P - then count F's up
                FCount++;
                // If there was P char counted before (> 0) - print it and reset counter
                if (PCount > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(PCount + " P ");
                    PCount = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        // Before go to next "row" - print remained P or F counts and again, reset counters
        if (PCount > 0)
        {
            Console.Write(PCount + " P ");
            PCount = 0;
        }
        else if (FCount > 0)
        {
            Console.Write(FCount + " F ");
            FCount = 0;
        }

        // Go new "row"
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Compressed output:

[image]

**UPD.**
My answer is just solution for a provided example source and example output. **@Dmitry Bychenko**'s solution is **universal**, not dependent on any two specific characters so in general use I recommend his way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (you can [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PSSiF0) with the code):

```
public static string Compress(char[,] source) {
  if (null == source || source.GetLength(0) <= 0 || source.GetLength(1) <= 0)
    return "";

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  for (int row = 0; row < source.GetLength(0); ++row) {
    if (sb.Length > 0)
      sb.AppendLine(); 

    int count = 0;
    char prior = '\0'; 
    bool left = true;

    for (int col = 0; col < source.GetLength(1); ++col) {
      if (count == 0 || prior == source[row, col]) 
        count += 1;
      else {
        if (!left)
          sb.Append(' ');

        left = false;
        sb.Append($"{count} {prior}");
        count = 1; 
      }
      
      prior = source[row, col];     
    }

    if (!left)
      sb.Append(' ');

    sb.Append($"{count} {prior}");     
  }  

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

**Demo:**

```
    char[,] test = new char[,] {
        {'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'},
        {'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'},
    };
    
    Console.WriteLine(Compress(test));
```

**Outcome:**

```
4 a
1 a 1 b 2 c
```